# How to handle Enter key press event on a Grid which is inside DataTemplate

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I have a GridView, and inside the DateTemplate of that GridView I have a grid and for that I want to handle the enter key event to be handled. Right now I am using Tapped event and it's working fine when clicked via mouse. I also tried using Keyup and Keydown event but none of them is firing.

Xaml Code:

```
  <DataTemplate x:Key="NormalTemplate" x:DataType="models:ProductLocal">
        <Grid Height="140" Width="140"  Tag="{Binding}" Tapped="TappedEvent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50"  Margin="4" Grid.Row="0" TextWrapping="WrapWholeWords" MaxLines="2" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"></TextBlock>
            <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" MaxLines="2" TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis">

                        <Run Text="{x:Bind SomeText}"></Run>
            </TextBlock>
            <customcontrols:CustomButton Grid.Row="2" Margin="4" Tag="{Binding}" Style="{StaticResource ButtonNoHoverStyle}" HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Tapped="EditProduct_Tapped">
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image Source="../Assets/Icons/iconEditNormal.png" Height="44" CacheMode="BitmapCache"></Image>
                </Button.Content>
            </customcontrols:CustomButton>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an event when mouse button is clicked try using

```
MouseUp="UserControl1_MouseUp" MouseDown="UserControl1_MouseDown"
```

according of your necessities. Tapped event is for touch displays, and key events are for handling the interaction with keyboard.

Comment: I want to achieve similar functionality as of Tapped event for the enter key. So is there any way I can bind Enter press with Tapped event?

Comment: I tried with normal button and it works with KeyUp event. Maybe the problem is your customcontrols:CustomButton.

Comment: I want to achieve it for entire Grid not just to b button inside it.

Comment: Ok, I think to understand. Try to remove the textblocks from your grid and put instead textboxes, then set them to IsReadOnly if you want they are not editable. So You can use KeyUp and KeyDown  events.

Answer (score 0):

I have done some tries and this is my grid:

```
<Grid Name="test" Height="140" KeyUp="Grid_KeyUp" Background="LightBlue" >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <TextBox Text="txttest" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50"  Margin="4" Grid.Row="0" IsReadOnly="True" 
                       ></TextBox>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Margin="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  TextWrapping="Wrap" >
            </TextBox>
            <Button Grid.Row="2" Margin="4,4,0,-9"   
                    HorizontalContentAlignment="Right" 
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <Button.Content>
                    <Image  Height="44" ></Image>
                </Button.Content>
            </Button>
        </Grid>
```

code behind:

```
private void Grid_KeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.Key.ToString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

To have a `Grid` capture keyboard input, it has only one option - an control inside the `Grid` has focus and does not handle the input, so it bubbles up to the `Grid`.

The `Grid` itself cannot have focus, as only classes deriving from `Control` can be focused, and `Grid` is just a layout control, which doesn't have this feature.

To solve this however, you can add the `KeyDown` event to the `GridView` itself and then get use the `SelectedItem` to know which item was selected when the <kbd>Enter</kbd> button was pressed.

In XAML you set the `KeyDown` event on `GridView`:

```
<GridView x:Name="MyGridView" KeyDown="GridView_KeyDown">
```

And now in the code-behind:

```
private void Grid_KeyDown(object sender, KeyRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var gridView = (GridView)sender;
    if (e.Key == Windows.System.VirtualKey.Enter)
    {
        var selectedItem = gridView.SelectedItem;
        //do something
    }
}
```